# Nodejs promises - how to catch function that does not resolve the promise?

Tags: node.js, promise

Is there a way to catch the case when one of the functions does not resolve the promise and to output message about it?

This is my code:

```
var Q = require("q");

var badFunction = function (resolve, reject, notify) {
    console.log('bad function');
}

var q = Q.Promise(badFunction)
.then(function (output) {
    console.log('bad function returned: ' + output);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('catch');
    throw err;
}).done();
```

This is what I see in console:

```
Polinas-MacBook:me3 polina$ node spike
bad function
Polinas-MacBook:me3 polina$
```

Comment: You're not resolving the promise, or returning a new promise from `heavyFunction`

Comment: Thank you, @sterling-archer. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure everything is completed, I should do loop with condition q.inspect().state at the end of my console app.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function run(){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   heavyFunction.then(() => {
    ...some code
    console.log(heavy code);
    resolve();
   }).catch(error) => {
    ... some code
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
   });
});
```

Comment: There is a cool package out there too called request-promise, it takes a lot of the extra code out of using a promise.  I will add it to my answer above...

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to either resolve or reject a promise. Otherwise it will never call the then or the catch block. If you want to react on an error simply call `reject(err)`.

```
var badFunction = function (resolve, reject, notify) {
    console.log('bad function');
    reject(new Error('an error'));
}
```

Comment: @johannes_merz, it is ok that it never call then or catch. I expect the process to never end. But it ends.

Comment: what do you want then? Check if the promise is still pending?

Comment: @johannes_merz, I like this direction. How can I do this? I put console.log(q) after 'done();' and got 'undefined'.